# How should the 10 helicopters be distributed so that the probability of finding the airplane is the highest?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I tried to solve this problem:

> An airplane could crash in one of two areas equally likely. When a
> helicopter is sent to search for it in the first area, it finds the
> airplane with probability 0.2 and in the second area 0.5. How should
> the 10 helicopters be distributed so that the probability of finding
> the airplane is the highest?

My solution to the problem:
Let P(A) be the probability of finding an airplane in any region.
B1 - event that the airplane is in the first area.
B2 - event that the airplane is in the second area.
Hence: 
$P(A\mid B1) = {1-(1-0.2)^k}$ 
$P(A\mid B2) = {1-(1-0.5)^{10-k}}$ 
Does this mean that using formula of full probability: 
$P(A) = P(A\mid B1)P(B1)+P(A\mid B2)P(B2)$, where ${P(B1)=P(B2) = 1/2}$ 
If so, then we should then find the point of maximum of this function, which would be the answer (rounded to integers)?

Comment: Apparently the definition of the event $A$ is "the aircraft is found, with $k$ helicopters assigned to B1". That should be clearly stated, not some vague sentence that doesn't even define $k$. And yes, you should find the maximum of the function. but instead of just "rounding it to integers", you should check both of the nearest integers to the maximum to see which provides the higher probability (it is possible that the closest integer can give a lower probability). And even there I am assuming the curve has only one local maximum. (This is obvious to me, but is it to you?)

Comment: I think the problem itself should be clarified, likely it means the conditional probability of a helicopter finding the plane, given the plane is in area 1 and hte helicopter is in area 1, is $0.2$ (so we don't always find the plane even if we check the correct location).  Also the helicopter findings are conditionally independent given their location and the plane's location.